# stopping activity indicator after tableView is loaded

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiactivityindicatorview

I am having difficulty trying to stop my activity indicator, where should "self.removeLoadingScreen()" be placed? It spins endlessly after the table view is loaded with data, I thought it would be ideal to place the removeLoadingScreen() under the animateTable function but that was incorrect.

```
   var refresher: UIRefreshControl!

func showSpinnerWhileFetchingData() {
    refresher.beginRefreshing()
    myTableView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(0, myTableView.contentOffset.y - refresher.frame.size.height), animated: true)

    let qualityOfServiceClass = QOS_CLASS_BACKGROUND

    let backgroundQueue = DispatchQueue.global(Int(qualityOfServiceClass.rawValue), 0)
    backgroundQueue.async(execute: {[unowned self] in
        //fetch you data here. you are now on a background queue
        //to quick test it, uncomment the code below
        //for i in 1...2000 {
        //    self.yourArrayThatIsPopulatingTheTable.append("\(i) hot potatoes")
        //}

        DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: { () -> Void in
            self.myTableView.reloadData()
            self.refresher.endRefreshing()
        })
    })

}
func refreshData(sender: UIRefreshControl) {


    refresher.endRefreshing()
    myTableView.reloadData()

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Remove those lines from setLoadingScreen:

```
self.spinner.startAnimating()
self.myTableView.addSubview(loadingView)
```

and add them to refreshData:

```
func refreshData(sender: UIRefreshControl) {

    myTableView.addSubview(loadingView) //here 
    spinner.startAnimating() //also, start the spinner
    myTableView.reloadData()
    refreshControl.endRefreshing()
}
```

and it should work as expected. 
What was happening is that in viewDidLoad, when you were calling setLoadingScreen, you were not only setting the loadingView, but you were also adding it to the view hierarchy (thus displaying it).

Also, don't forget to remove the loadingView when you are done with it, as Jitendra said.

LATER EDIT:
If all you want is a normal refreshControl, with no customization, you can get rid of most of the code. All you need is:

declare this:

```
 var refresher: UIRefreshControl!
```

in viewDidLoad:

```
    refresher = UIRefreshControl()
    refresher.addTarget(self, action: "refreshData:", forControlEvents: .ValueChanged)
    tableView.addSubview(refresher)
```

in refreshData:

```
  //get the new data
    refresher.endRefreshing()
    tableView.reloadData()
```

You don't need the "loadingView", "spinner", "loadingLabel", you don't need the "setLoadingScreen" and "removeLoadingScreen" functions. The UIRefreshControl will do all the work for you. Let me know if it works.

LATER LATER EDIT (Swift 2)

If you also want to start the refreshcontrol programatically when you first show the table and have it running while you fetch the data:

```
func showSpinnerWhileFetchingData() {
    refresher.beginRefreshing()
    tableView.setContentOffset(CGPointMake(0, tableView.contentOffset.y - refresher.frame.size.height), animated: true)

    let qualityOfServiceClass = QOS_CLASS_BACKGROUND
    let backgroundQueue = dispatch_get_global_queue(qualityOfServiceClass, 0)
    dispatch_async(backgroundQueue, {[unowned self] in
        //fetch you data here. you are now on a background queue
        //to quick test it, uncomment the code below 
        //for i in 1...2000 {
        //    self.yourArrayThatIsPopulatingTheTable.append("\(i) hot potatoes")
        //}

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
            self.tableView.reloadData()
            self.refresher.endRefreshing()
        })
    })

}
```

Call this function in viewWillAppear.
And get rid of the animateTable function, unless you really want the effect of animating row by row, in which case:

1. you either let it as it is, and it won't be considerably visible (actually, not at all visible...), but it will slow your UI a bit
2. or, if you want to take your time and you want to trade responsiveness for special effects, you have to set a completion handler
   and animate each row after the previous finished animating, which is another topic.

I hope it helps :)

EDIT the last edit, translated to Swift 3

```
func showSpinnerWhileFetchingData() {
    refresher.beginRefreshing()

    tableView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: 0, y: tableView.contentOffset.y - refresher.frame.size.height), animated: true)

    let qualityOfServiceClass = DispatchQoS.QoSClass.background
    let backgroundQueue = DispatchQueue.global(qos: qualityOfServiceClass)
    backgroundQueue.async(execute: {[unowned self] in
        //fetch you data here. you are now on a background queue
        //to quick test it, uncomment the code below and modify the name of the array to match the array you are using
        //for i in 1...2000 {
        //    self.yourArrayThatIsPopulatingTheTable.append("\(i) hot potatoes")
        //}
        //sleep(5)  //alternately, you can use this to test. don't forget to remove this sleep line after you test

        DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: { () -> Void in
            self.tableView.reloadData()
            self.refresher.endRefreshing()
        })
    })

}
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? In which ways do you want to customize your refreshControl? I'm trying to see if it couldn't be done easier.

Comment: i want the activity indicator to show as soon as the view is opened because it usually takes a short moment until the table view data is retrieved

Comment: oh, I see. hold on.

Comment: I edited the answer to include what you asked for. See the LATER LATER EDIT.

Comment: i removed the animate table function and tried your code, Xcode fixed some errors in the function however still has an error 'cannot invoke global with argument list int' and also 'argument labels do not match overloads' on .setContentOffSet

Comment: :) I gave you the Swift 2 code, sorry. Will update it for Swift 3 asap.

Answer (score 0):

You should remove the `loadingView` from super view when you are done with it.

So change your method as:

```
fileprivate func removeLoadingScreen() {

self.spinner.stopAnimating()
self.loadingLabel.isHidden = true
//when table have data, after refreshing, remove the loadView from the table view
loadingView.removeFromSuperView()
}
```

and call this method as table view refreshing done

```
func refreshData(sender: UIRefreshControl) {

  myTableView.reloadData()
  refreshControl.endRefreshing()

 //remove loading screen view now
 removeLoadingScreen()

}
```

Comment: Where should I place my new removeLoadingScreen() method?

Comment: i tried it, it still does not stop on its own, it only stops and disappears after I pull down to refresh table

Comment: If you want only remove spinner when reloading is done, then you should call removeLoadingScreen() in completion block of animation of table view. Hope this help you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
fileprivate func removeLoadingScreen() {    
    self.spinner.stopAnimating() // use this two lines anywhere you need to hide indicator
    loadingView.isHidden = true
}
```